# can you add the echos to the xml log report using PHPUnit?

Tags: xml, phpunit, report

Is it possible to get your echos during a test to show in the xml report using `--log-junit`?
I got a function in my test that looks for error tooltips during the test and I echo them out and I can see them in the cmd log but not in the xml report. How do I make them show in the report?

Answer (score 0):

You should try the json logger it export even the test output. Otherwise you may extend the Junit logger in order to do the same as the [junit format](https://svn.jenkins-ci.org/trunk/hudson/dtkit/dtkit-format/dtkit-junit-model/src/main/resources/com/thalesgroup/dtkit/junit/model/xsd/junit-4.xsd) would support it as well.

The xsd contains:

```
<xs:element name="system-err" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="system-out" type="xs:string"/>

<xs:element name="testcase">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
                ...
            <xs:element ref="system-out" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element ref="system-err" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>

 ...
```

Comment: Okey, can you recommend another format to save the PHPUnit reports in that does support this?

Comment: Okey, I see that the json log supports echos so guess i'll build a html repport from json instead of xml, thanks for the answers.

Comment: Sorry my first answer was wrong. Thanks for helping *me* (hihi :)